# React-big-calendar Toolbar access outside calendar component

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am trying to understand if it is possible with `react-big-calendar` to have a custom Toolbar with `next/prev` buttons and also the other buttons **outside** the normal calendar component or also **access to them from outside**, **creating a custom Toolbar placed another position then the usual one**?

Answer (score 0):

If your `date` and `view` props are controlled props, then you could (technically) create an external toolbar, using your `localizer` for things like date/label formatting (if you want that). It won't have access to any of your Calendar's internal props, but it will allow you to control basic navigation. Just have buttons that set the `date` or `view` to what you want them to be. And set your `toolbar` prop to `false` to prevent the default toolbar from being displayed.